# cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d248d.lib'

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2012 with opencv version 2.4.12.
I know the reason behind this error .
I want to modify the library name from **opencv_calib3d248d.lib** to **opencv_calib3d2412d.lib** .
I have given list of libraries that atre present in **c:OpenCV\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib** library in linker option of **VS2012**.(in additional dependency).I have given the library path also in linker option .But still it is giving same error message for opencv version 248.

Can any one tell where I need to modify opencv version name from 248 to 2412 .

Answer (score 0):

yes~
248 means version 2.4.8
2412 means version 2.4.12

Comment: open your opencv file ,for me is `D:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib`or `D:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib`(maybe your path is different from mine.), and you'll find the file name is like"24**.lib". that means the version is 2.4.**   When you add extra lib, the name should be fit.

Comment: Some conduction only fits the author's version, not yours. So you have to change it to let it fit yours.

Comment: **But I do not mean you change the source file name, but the extra lib which you add to your VS project. I mean according to the source file name to change the name in the VS**